# import data from xls and display in barchart

Tags: ios, graph, charts, ios6

there is an xls file which needs to be displayed as a bar graph and on click on the column it needs to display data from xls file pertaining to that column representation on an IPAD .I am new to this but how do I proceed from here.Since its in xls format what can I do with that is there an inbuilt function which converts it into csv ?.Its an offline project .Kindly help me .Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why not try "graphics" in place of "graphs" for more hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/dhoerl/DHlibxls  It has a nice wrapper around libxls.  There are no built-in functions to convert from xls to csv, but you can easily write your own using this library.

I should note that libxls is LGPL, so be careful.